# R - Keep newest data that is not NA, unless only NA available

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, na

I have a dataset with three columns: year, city, value which looks like this:

```
year = c(2010, 2013, 2010, 2013, 2013)
city = c("Berlin","Berlin", "Munich", "Munich", "Frankfurt")
value = c(1234, NA, NA, 6372, NA)
data <- data.frame(year, value1, value2)

 year    city    value
1 2010    Berlin   1234
2 2013    Berlin     NA
3 2010    Munich     NA
4 2013    Munich   6372
5 2013 Frankfurt     NA
```

I would like to know how to subset this so that I keep only the newest data that is available, so that at the end I am left with data like this:

```
 year    city    value
1 2010    Berlin   1234
2 2013    Munich   6372
3 2013 Frankfurt     NA
```

If I subset on the highest year, I get NAs where for that year there isn't data. If I subset on `!is.na()`, I lose all rows where there's *only* NA available.

What I want to do specifically is get the highest year for a given city with data, unless there are only NAs for that city, then the highest year with NA. How would I go about that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to subset? From your example it seems you don't want to subset for the highest year, is there another variable that you don't show here?

Comment: Ah, no: I want to subset for the city column: the highest year with data for a given city, unless there are only NAs for that city, then the highest year with NA.

Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'city', we specify the 'i' as the 'year' in descending `order` index, `if` there are `any` non-NA 'value', we Subset the 'Data.table' based on the index of the first non-NA 'value' or `else` return the Subset of Data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[order(-year), if(any(!is.na(value)))  
            .SD[which(!is.na(value))[1L]] else .SD, by = city]
```

Or a compact option by @David Arenburg where we get the index from `which.max`

```
setDT(data)[order(-year), .SD[which.max(!is.na(value))], by = city]
```

Or use a modification using `.I` to make it faster

```
setDT(data)[data[order(-year), .I[which.max(!is.na(value))], by = city]$V1]
```

Comment: this is really awesome, thanks! tried it on my real dataset and it worked perfectly :) one question though: if I have multiple years for a city with NA (so 2010, Frankfurt, NA; 2011, Frankfurt, NA; 2013, Frankfurt, NA) it keeps all of these years. How do I keep only the newest year for that case?

Comment: Or just `setDT(data)[order(-year), .SD[which.max(!is.na(value))], by = city]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg That was very good.  Actually, I was trying similar with `which`.  Was on a call, so couldn't focus on it

Comment: The difference between `which` and `which.max` is that in case of everything is `FALSE`, `which` will return nothing while `which.max` will return the first row. Compare `which(FALSE)` and `which.max(FALSE)`. Either-way, you can add it to your answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose, roundabout approach using `dplyr`. It also works for your case where you have multiple years of `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(all_na = all(is.na(value)),
         remove = ifelse(all_na,
                         year != max(year),
                         is.na(value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!remove) %>%
  select(-all_na, -remove)
```

Answer (score 0):

`max_pos(x)` returns the position in `x` of the last non-NA element of `x` or if there are no non-NA elements it returns the last position of `x`.  `is_max` returns a logical which is TRUE in the maximum position and FALSE elsewhere. Note that `ave` will coerce its result to the type of its first argument so we use `!!` to turn it back to logical.  Finally we then subset out those elements.  This assumes the input is sorted by year within city as is the case in the question.

Note that `max_pos` was made compact by using these facts:

- in `seq_along(x) * 0*x` the `0*x` is a vector of zeros and NAs so adding it NAs out the corresponding elements of `seq_along(x)`.  That is, it gives the same result as `replace(seq_along(x), is.na(x), NA)` which could be used in its place.
- `which.max` returns a zero length result if `x` is all NA values and `c(arg1, arg2)[1]` gives the same result as `if (length(arg1) == 0) arg2 else arg1` which could be used in its place.

*No packages are used.*

```
max_pos <- function(x) c(which.max(seq_along(x) + 0*x), length(x))[1]
is_max <- function(x) seq_along(x) == max_pos(x)
subset(data, !!ave(value, city, FUN = is_max))
```

giving:

```
  year      city value
1 2010    Berlin  1234
4 2013    Munich  6372
5 2013 Frankfurt    NA
```